# antd design select placeholder issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, create-react-app, antd

I am using antd design in my React app.

Here's a code snippet where I am facing the issues :

```
<Select
     showSearch
     optionFilterProp = "children"
     placeholder = "Select Company"
     value = "{this.state.company}"
     name = "company"
     onSelect = "{this.handleCompanyChange}"
    >
```

Now it shows the correct value selected if `this.state.company` is not `null`. But if `this.state.company` is `empty` or `null`, placeholder doesn't shows up.

How can I solve this issue so that the placeholder appears if `value` is null?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

set this.state.company to be undefined instead of null.

Comment: Do you mean like this :  this.state.company=undefined ?

Comment: `value = {this.state.company?this.state.company:undefined}`

Comment: You can also simplify the above statement with value={this.state.company || undefined}

Comment: @afc163, Can you guys fix this? It should show the placeholder for null too.

Comment: shortcut `value = { this.state.company || undefined }`

Comment: hi, 
It's is not working for me: <Select showSearch placeholder="Select category" value={undefined}>

Comment: you should put something to the value instead of just undefined @JyotiDuhan, but can you explain why should it be undefined?

Comment: ant design should work on both undefined or null

Answer (score 6):

you should update as below:

```
<Select
     showSearch
     optionFilterProp = "children"
     placeholder = "Select Company"
     value = {this.state.company || undefined} ---- update this line
     name = "company"
     onSelect = "{this.handleCompanyChange}"
    >
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be set to `undefined` instead of `null` or `""` empty string.

```
this.props.form.setFieldsValue({
    myFieldName: undefined
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the the same issue, heres the solution:
Code snippet for ant design select

```
<Select key="1" value={this.getStateValue()} showSearch allowClear placeholder='Select Weight' onChange={onWeightChange}>
  {options}
</Select>
```

where getStateValue will be this:

```
getStateValue = () => {
    const { value } = this.state;
    if (value) {
      return value;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed from:

```
const [value, updateValue] = useState("");
```

To:

```
const [value, updateValue] = useState(undefined);
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Form.create() of the Antd then there is another cool way to set/get the value of the form. Note that in this method the components (Select and others) have to be inside a `<Form>` element. Also the enclosing class should be passed in Form.create() object as props, as shown below:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Form.create()(YourClassName));
```

This way we have **this.props.form** available in the props. This will have an important function named getFieldDecorator, as shown below:

```
const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
```

Every Input component must be wrapped inside a , see below:

```
<FormItem>
   { getFieldDecorator('prefix', {
      initialValue: '86',
    })(
      <Select style={{ width: 70 }}>
        <Option value="86">+86</Option>
        <Option value="87">+87</Option>
      </Select>
    );}
</FormItem>
```

As you can see above, this is more easier way to set initial value to the form elements.

Note that at times when you need to set values of the form elements in functions programatically then you can use **setFieldsValue**, **setFields** etc.

*Before using getFieldsValue getFieldValue setFieldsValue and so on, please make sure that corresponding field had been registered with getFieldDecorator.*
Please refer https://ant.design/components/form/?locale=en-US#Form-fields for more information on coordinated controls.
Example:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (someCheckHere){
            this.props.form.setFieldsValue({
                company: userData.companyName
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the image posted, you need to target the name and try to set it to null if its an empty string, this should work.[image]