# antd select placeholder value doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using antd library in my react project and using select from there.
But the placeholder value for select doesn't show up. I am using below code following an another question already asked at stackoverflow ([antd design select placeholder issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546300/antd-design-select-placeholder-issues))

```
<Select showSearch placeholder="Select category" value={undefined}>
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Why is your value undefined?

Comment: It is suggested as per the link of other similar question asked earlier